# Significato dell'espressione "per quassú"

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Il ragazzo se ne andò in giro due giorni qua e là, perché in realtà era un bravo ragazzo, pieno di idee e d’espedienti e **per quassú** anche quasi educato: salí alle torbe, e ai calanchi, ed ai pascoli e non riuscí a trovar piú di tanto.

Non capisco bene qual è il significato dell'espressione "per quassú". Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quassu) si può leggere questa spiegazione per l'avverbio "quassú":

> In questo luogo qua in alto o più in alto (contr. di *quaggiù*): *q. in cima; sono q. in soffitta; vieni un momento q.; come sei salito fin q.?*; preceduto da prep.: *di q.* (o *da q.*) *non riesco a vederti*. Talora può indicare non luogo più elevato, ma posto più a settentrione rispetto a quello dove sta la persona a cui si scrive o si telefona: *spero che tu mi raggiunga presto q. a Torino*.

Le definizioni che si trovano in altri dizionari sono simili. Tuttavia, questo non sembra avere molto senso nel contesto del brano precedente: il ragazzo per quel luogo in alto era quasi educato? Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "per quassú" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quella frase “per quassù” si può parafrasare con “per i canoni di quassù” o “per essere uno di quassù”. Cioè, altrove (in città, forse) quel ragazzo non sarebbe stato considerato particolarmente educato ma “quassù” (il paesino dove si svolge il racconto) lo si può ritenere “quasi educato”.

Tra l'altro – ma forse su questo si potrebbe porre una domanda a parte – quando si dice “su” o “giù” in contesti simili, non ci si riferisce necessariamente a una maggiore elevazione. Se uno dice “Vado su al paese a trovare i miei”, non pensa necessariamente alla quota del paese (ma d'altronde in varie parti d'Italia i paesi sono su colli e monti, mentre le città sono nelle valli, nelle pianure o sul mare).

<sup>Fammelo scrivere in piccolo: a volte è qualcosa di vagamente simile a *uptown* e *downtown* in inglese, dove una denotazione topografica precisa ha assunto successivamente un senso più sociale che geografico.</sup>

Comment: In catalano accade una cosa simile. Per esempio, molta gente dice "pujo a Barcelona" (cioè, "salgo a Barcellona") e forse arrivano dal nord e da una maggiore altitudine.